# Python how to insert objects in nested lists

Tags: python, json

How do I insert an object in nested lists. I get json response that doesn't return a a certain object for certain a condition

data.json

*Note: in 'steps' list, the 3rd index did not return result*

```
[
{
  "elements": [
    {
      "keyword": "Scenario", 
      "name": "valid user can login site", 
      "steps": [
        {
          "name": "a valid user name and password", 
          "result": {
            "status": "passed"
          }
        }, 
        { 
          "name": "a valid user clicking on the login button after typing in user name and password", 
          "result": { 
            "status": "passed"
          }
        }, 
        { 
          "name": "map should display" 
        }
      ]
    }
  ], 
  "keyword": "Feature", 
  "name": "login", 
  "status": "passed"
}
]
```

**What I want to achieve:**

*I want to insert a 'result' object if it is absent*

```
[
{
  "elements": [
    {
      "keyword": "Scenario", 
      "name": "valid user can login site", 
      "steps": [
        {
          "name": "a valid user name and password", 
          "result": {
            "status": "passed"
          }
        }, 
        { 
          "name": "a valid user clicking on the login button after typing in user name and password", 
          "result": { 
            "status": "passed"
          }
        }, 
        { 
          "name": "map should display" 
          "result": { 
            "status": "skipped"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ], 
  "keyword": "Feature", 
  "name": "login", 
  "status": "passed"
}
]
```

**What i've done so far (pseudo):**

```
with open('data.json') as data_file:  
     data = json.load(data_file) 

#nested for loops??
#if x.has_key('result') == False
#insert result object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should word for you:

```
for step in data[0]['elements'][0]['steps']:
    if 'result' not in step:
        step['result'] = {"status": "skipped"}
```

More generic solution:

```
for d in data:
    for element in d['elements']:
        for step in element['steps']:
            if 'result' not in step:
                step['result'] = {"status": "skipped"}
```